# DataGridView ComboboxCell doesn't save its value to database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing a simple Windows Forms desktop application in Visual Studio 2010. It connects to the 2-table database, shows values. The user changes some values in tables, and they should be saved.
I have two tables: `Banks` and `Orders`. `Orders` has a foreign key relation to `Banks` (it has a `bank_id` field).
I created a `Form`, I created a `Dataset` and added data to it by dragging and dropping the two tables from the `Server Explorer` panel of VS2010.
Then I added a `DataGridView` to my `Form` by dragging and dropping table `Orders` to it.
That was a working project, I could change data, save it, and it would be saved in the database.

The only concern was that it is inconvenient to put bank ids instead of their names into the table. I wanted to have a `ComboBoxCell` in my table instead.
I used a visual editor to delete a column `bank_id` from the `DataGridView` on my `Form`. Instead, I added the following code to the `Form` constructor:

```
public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colFilterType = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            colFilterType.HeaderText = "Bank";
            colFilterType.DataSource = dataSet1.banks;
            colFilterType.ValueMember = "id";
            colFilterType.DisplayMember = "display_name";
            colFilterType.ValueType = typeof(int);
            ordersDataGridView.Columns.Add(colFilterType);

        }
```

Comment: table `Banks` has fields `id` and `display_name`.

It works fine as a `ComboBoxCell`, but it has 2 problems:
1. When the form is started, all values in that column (only in that column) are empty (instead of taking them from the database).
2. When I change some date (e.g. add a row), all values except for values in `Bank` column are saved successfully to the database. But values in the `Bank` column are not saved.
I think that something is wrong with the binding of `Bank` column with my data (`Dataset` or something like that).
Could anybody please help me with solving the problem? What should I do to save all data from the `Bank` column to the database as well?

Comment: you can hide the bank_id column instead of deleting it. you can set visible property of column to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate the initial values set the property `DataPropertyName`  to DB column name.

`colFilterType.DataPropertyName = "id"`

This should also solve your update problem.